# How to run a Julia file, which uses a package, in Python?

Tags: python, julia

I'm using PyJulia to run a Julia file in Python. The file I want to run uses a package, that is already installed on Julia. But it still gives the following error:

```
JULIA: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package LowRankApprox not found in current path: Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("LowRankApprox")` to install the LowRankApprox package.
```

Why are you giving this error, if the package has already been installed on Julia?

Comment: It might be that you did not `Pkg.activate` the right environment... Could you please give more details? In which environment did you install `LowRankApprox` and `PyJulia`? If you run `import Pkg; Pkg.status()` in a fresh Julia REPL, what does it produce?

Comment: @françois I installed the LowRankApprox package on Julia and PyJulia on Python. When I run Pkg.activate on Julia the answer is: activate (generic function with 3 methods). When I run Pkg.status () on Julia, several installed packages appear, including LowRankApprox. Do I have to put a path to the package?

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure that the correct Julia environment got activated by pyjulia. Try running in Python:

```
from julia import Pkg
Pkg.activate("/home/user/.julia/environments/v1.5") #use the correct path
```

You need to use the directory path exactly the same that Julia is using (this is the folder where `Project.toml` is stored). To check what is the correct path run in Julia:

```
julia> using Pkg; Pkg.activate()
 Activating environment at `/home/user/.julia/environments/v1.5/Project.toml`
```

Last but not least, for the best results I recommend using the Python Anaconda that gets installed together with Julia (`using Pkg; Pkg.add("PyCall");Pkg.add("Conda");using Conda;Conda.add("whateveranacondapackageyouneed")`). It gets installed to your Julia folder and the Anaconda version that gets installed this way has been tested against integration issues.

Comment: Running in Python: from Julia import Pkg, gives package not installed. When I try to install it gives: Install packages failed. I found the path to the directory Julia is using, but I don't know where to put it. I'm sorry I'm new to this. I've been using PyCharm for a long time to make Python Scripts. Do you think it is better to switch to Anaconda? Is that why I'm having such a hard time at PyJulia?

Comment: It should be `from julia import Pkg` NOT `from Julia import Pkg`

Comment: If you are not a master of  configuration management use the Anaconda built-into Julia (see my answer)